# What tasks should I try to accomplish in the first 20 days?

Tags: dont-starve

Clearly Don't Starve is a sandbox game, and you have quite a bit of freedom to play the game as you please.  (Quite frankly, I've spent a lot of the time wandering around the game fairly aimlessly.)

But, I'm wondering if there are certain tasks that should take a higher priority within the first 20 days.

Clearly, building a Science Machine and/or an Alchemy Machine are very high priorities.  And, next I typically have been trying to acquire some warmer clothing.

But, where should I be focusing my attention from here?

Should I be building structures?  Farms?  Exploring the landscape?

Basically, I'm looking for a Quick Start guide to having a successful long game.

Comment: I would advise watching a Let's Play of a skilled players early game. It will teach you the answers to these questions, and also help with learning some combat tricks and other stuff that wont be obvious from text

Comment: I'm not familiar with Let's Play.  Do you have a link?

Comment: Let's play is a genre of commentated playthroughs. I wasn't specifically suggesting one in particular since the ones i watched were during early beta, but here is an example of what I'm talking about. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRsMA_YVVAQ

Comment: You could watch Volx or joeshmocoolstuff for gameplay and tips and tricks videos...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You said it, it's a sandbox game. Do what you want, there are a lot of different ways to survive 100 days.

Since you specifically asked for the first 20 days (and winter hits on day 21, so that's convenient), here's a **small checklist** for your pleasure. Feel free to edit in stuff you think is missing:

#### Days 1-5: gathering

Explore as much as you can, gather food to stay alive, and some basic resources:

- Twigs, Grass
- Flint, Axe, Logs, Pick, Stone, Gold
- Science Machine, backpack, spear

Find a balance between picking up just what you need & picking up everything you can. You'll want to cover some ground.

#### Days 6-10: settling

Building a small camp to ensure food production. You'll be needing manure, so close to beefalos (or a pig camp) is advised.

- Science machine, fire pit, crock pot, drying rack, farms
- Lightning rod, shovel, berry bushes, saplings, grass tufts
- Chests, log suit, football helmet (if you can).

#### Days 10-15: improving the camp

Explore the lands around you, bring the good stuff to your camp:

- Bee boxes, flowers, fireflies.
- Survive your first hound attack.
- Dig up graves for the pig king. Find gears and create an ice box.
- Grab some pig skins and build a few pig houses nearby.

#### Days 15-20: prepare for winter

Winter is coming. It will be cold, you'll find it harder to find food & sanity.

- Shave beefalo, kill spiders, collect rabbits. Make winter clothing.
- Cut rocks, make a heat stone.
- Gather honey, taffy, jerky. Craft a top hat. You'll need the sanity.
- Boomerang.
- Sleeping roll or tent to convert excess food into easy sanity (and skip boring nights)
- Drying rack, in order to make meat take much longer to spoil and give sanity

Comment: +1 will be trying this later.  Great looking starter guide.

Comment: Still up to date?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy: for Don't Starve (classic, not Together or Shipwrecked), starting in autumn: yeah, these guidelines remain applicable.